# "An error occurred on the server." in web browser on all XML web service errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I'm not sure how to present this problem, but I've created a web service that returns XML to the user, and while debugging, on all errors, all I receive is this exact text in the web browser:

```
 An error occurred on the server.
```

In every other C# application I've created over the years, errors break within the code.  Obviously, this makes it very difficult to debug code, especially when the error happens prior to any code being entered.

I really don't know where to look.

I searched my solution for this text, and it doesn't exist in any of my files.

web.config contains:

```
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <webServices>
      <diagnostics suppressReturningExceptions="true" />
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpSoap" />
        <add name="HttpPost" />
        <add name="HttpGet" />
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
```

I checked global.asax and it seems normal:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
```

The webservice class itself starts off like this:

```
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://CarReports.org")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class CarService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{


    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public CarOptionsModel CurrentOptions(string serialNo)
    {
        ...
    }
```

I really don't know where else to look, and Googling "An error occurred on the server." is impossible.

Comment: Have you tried adding an error filter? Also, look for the customErrors element in web.config.

Comment: I have no customErrors element.  Are you suggesting that I try putting an error filter in global.asax.cs?

Comment: Come to think of it, I did try adding "protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)" in global.asax and that was never hit.

Comment: No, I mean an `IExceptionFilter` (I think that's how it's called in ASP.NET MVC)

Comment: I just tried adding a System.Web.Mvc.ExceptionContext filter and it was not triggered during an error.  I'll try other methods though.  It sounds like it might be a good workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed this problem by enabling "Just My Code."  Perhaps I disabled it by mistake.

Debug->Options and Settings...->Debugging->General->Enable Just My Code